# How to read element value from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make all elements with class "reaction" react on click and I need to read element value.

in document ready I put

```
$(".reaction").click(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

but I cannot read value. How to read element on this way ?

Comment: which html element has the class .reaction ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "element value"? The 'value' attribute or the contained text/html?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if the matching elements have a "value" attribute:

```
    $(".reaction").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Well, if the elements have a value attribute, `this.value` will work (and it's faster as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can take attr value in pure element.


    http://jsfiddle.net/9Rw2p/2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
    $(".reaction").click(function() {
        console.log(this.textContent);
    });
```

It works fine for me